# How to get 3 divs to align horizontally, with height of 100%, inside a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

EDIT: Alignment fixed by adding floats. Height still doesn't fill 100% though. Updated look: https://gyazo.com/4030d76c62c106fae5fbbb07f062efdd

I have a footer container in which I want to have 3 columns (I have made them green, white and red for now so it's easier for you to see). Currently they're stacking vertically but I want them to be beside eachother and have a height of 100% to fill the height of whatever the container's height is. Here is an image of what it looks liek at the moment, please ignore the large black boxes, these are just so I can see where stuff is on the page but will evenutally be transparent etc. https://gyazo.com/12d0642e5fd9518a663606668ec06311

They each have a width of 33% because I want to follow responsive practices and I've currently tried removing all padding and margins etc from every div.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

HTML:

```
<div id="Page">

        <div id="content" class="wrapper">

        </div>      

        <div id="footer">
            <div id="footerContainer">
                <div id="footerLeft">
                    <p>
                    Test
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="footerCenter">
                    <p>
                    Test
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="footerRight">
                    <p>
                    Test
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>    <!-- footerContainer -->
        </div> <!-- Footer -->

    </div> <!-- Page -->
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    background-color: black;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: black;
}

#footerContainer {
    width: 60%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footerLeft {
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: darkolivegreen;
    padding: 0;
}

#footerCenter {
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0;
}

#footerRight {
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: firebrick;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: flex` to the `#footerContainer` rule, and change `max-height: 100%;` to `height: 100%;` in `#footerContainer`

```css
#content {
    background-color: black;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: black;
}

#footerContainer {
  display: flex;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footerLeft {
    width: 33%;
    background-color: darkolivegreen;
}

#footerCenter {
    width: 33%;
    background-color: white;
}

#footerRight {
    width: 33%;
    background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<div id="Page">

        <div id="content" class="wrapper">

        </div>      

        <div id="footer">
            <div id="footerContainer">
                <div id="footerLeft">
                    <p>
                    Test
                    </p>
                </div>
              <div id="footerCenter">
                    <p>
                    Test
                    </p>
                </div>
              <div id="footerRight">
                    <p>
                    Test
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>    <!-- footerContainer -->
        </div> <!-- Footer -->

    </div> <!-- Page -->
```

---

Here is a version where I simplified both markup and CSS

```css
#content {
  background-color: black;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#footer > div {
  width: 20%;
}
#footerLeft {
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}
#footerCenter {
  background-color: white;
}
#footerRight {
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<div id="Page">

  <div id="content" class="wrapper">

  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <div id="footerLeft">
      <p>
        Test
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="footerCenter">
      <p>
        Test
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="footerRight">
      <p>
        Test
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->

</div>
<!-- Page -->
```

---

One for older browsers, using `display: table`

```css
#content {
  background-color: black;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
#footerContainer {
  display: table;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#footerContainer > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
}
#footerLeft {
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}
#footerCenter {
  background-color: white;
}
#footerRight {
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<div id="Page">

  <div id="content" class="wrapper">

  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <div id="footerContainer">
      <div id="footerLeft">
        <p>
          Test
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="footerCenter">
        <p>
          Test
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="footerRight">
        <p>
          Test
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- footerContainer -->
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <!-- Footer -->

</div>
<!-- Page -->
```

Comment: Just after I posted I added float:left to all colums and that has fixed the problem, however still no success in getting the height to 100% Any ideas? @LGSon And thank you very much for your help, would it be fine how i've done it or would the display: flex be better practice?

Comment: @EthanBristow `display: flex` is better practice as it is the way to structure layout , which `float` were never ment for, still, sometimes it is used where `flexbox` can't/won't work. With `display: flex` they will keep height equal

Comment: Thanks @LGSon i've changed it to display:flex now and it's also worked which is nice as the code seems more efficient. Unfortunatley still getting the height issue though. I've added an updated image to the question. I'd like the divs to have a height matching that of the container.

Comment: @EthanBristow Updated my answer to fix the height issue

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left` to the 3 elements.
Don't repeat the properties, combine the selectors with comma.

To stretch the elements you will need to change `max-height` to `height` on `#footerContainer`.

```css
#content {
  background-color: black;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}

#footerContainer {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#footerLeft,
#footerCenter,
#footerRight {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

#footerLeft {
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}

#footerCenter {
  background-color: white;
}

#footerRight {
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<div id="Page">

  <div id="content" class="wrapper">

  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <div id="footerContainer">
      <div id="footerLeft">
        <p>
          Test
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="footerCenter">
        <p>
          Test
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="footerRight">
        <p>
          Test
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- footerContainer -->
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->

</div>
<!-- Page -->
```

Comment: Thankyou, just tried this myself after posting and it worked so i've updated the question. Still having an issue with the height filling 100% though if you know what's casuing that? Many thanks @pol

Comment: `max-height: 100%` --> `height: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
} 
#div1 {
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
#div2 {
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
}
#div3 {
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    height:100%;   
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="div1"><!--
--><div id="div2"><!--
--><div id="div3">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If the second div isn't perfectly aligned, try setting #container text-align to center. Is very important to use the comments to delete the space between the divs.